# Patching Falcon hook

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a api with a before hook. I want to patch it to my custom_function.
Any idea how do I do it? I have already patch `falcon.before` to my custom_falcon_before.

```
class TestModel(MyTestCase):
    def falcon_before(self, model_exists):
        return model_exists

    def model_exists(self, req, resp, resource, params, require_exists):
        pass

    @patch("app.views.expect_model_existence", side_effect=model_exists)
    @patch("falcon.before", side_effect=falcon_before)
    def test_delete(self, falcon_before, model_exists):
        import falcon
        print(falcon_before is falcon.before)
        print(model_exists is expect_model_existence)
```

second print is `False`.

My API model is as below

```
class SingleModel:

    @falcon.before(expect_model_existence, True)
    def on_delete(self, req, resp, model_id):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `expect_model_existence` to a separate module and patch it before the `view.py` will be imported

Place `print('too late')` in a module that contains `expect_model_existence` to verify that everything is OK.

Falcon doesn't provide something more comfortable :(